# connecting two IP addresses when NAT provider is down

Tags: nat, isp

I am coming from very strange country "Bosnia" and in our country we everything spit on three side by three confession. So we also have three ISP provides and there NAT providers also. Our company spreads branches all over territory and I have all of that providers.

From time to time It just happens to NAT providers do not see each others and to my branches can't reach servers if they have other ISP then first one.

When I call ISP provers to report a problem they just say something is wrong with NAT providers and it can take hours to I have connection again between branches with different ISPs.
Its hard to explain how is that that both of branches have internet access but they can't see each other

Now I asking You guys: IS there something what I can do to connect branches even when NAT providers do not allowing path to my public IP address at administration building where I hosts servers and have public static IP configured on FreeBSD

Comment: What exactly does a "NAT provider" provide?  This isn't something that typically exists.  Do you mean your ISPs all use CGN?  Also, how does the problem fit within your topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can tell from your question, you have different buildings on different WAN networks that cannot see each other.  There isn't much you can do if the ISP's are the problem.

The two suggestions i have are:

running dedicated links, which is expensive, 
setting up a central system that is visible by all the ISP's, probably outside the country.

without more, possibly clearer information i can't make a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If when you see the problem you can't get anywhere (not to google, theplanet, nothing) then there is nothing you can do. If you can get to some sites and you are in a small office, you could try Hamachi. If this is a larger business I would suggest looking for a host that both office can still get to while the NAT problems are going on.

I'm not familiar with that part of the world, but if you were able to get to theplanet.com (just an example) during a NAT issue you could rent a server at that datacenter, install openvpn on the server, and use that to bounce around the problem.

Comment: Yes during the NAT issue both of sides have internet connection and they can access sites such Google, etc But It can't see each other, otherwise It can't also see the sites of providers and their DNS.
Ill try with Hamachi.

Comment: in this case, rent a box in a data centre, and have VPNs from each branch office to it. I wouldn't use them as your main link, but you can manually fail over routing to them when you have issues.